# Discord bot getting a file attachement and reuploading it

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'd like to make a bot, to resend an image/file sent to a channel.

The bot get's the url of the file (message.attachments[0].url), but when I want to send it as a file, it says **FileNotFoundError**: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ....png

The bot was working and resending an image one single time, but then about 50 times, it's not.

```
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith("anon ") or message.content.startswith("Anon "):
        if message.attachments:
            await message.channel.send(f"{message.content[5:]}", file=discord.File(message.attachments[0].url))
```

Thank you for helping!

Comment: `discord.File` expects a path, not a URL.

Comment: then how did it work one time? (for the first time it was working, then not)

Comment: Not sure, but it shouldn't.

Comment: file=await discord.File(message.attachments[0].url)

It works, if I put await before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert attachment to file. You can use [`to_file()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Attachment.to_file) function like this:

```py
await message.channel.send(f"{message.content[5:]}", file=await message.attachments[0].to_file()
```

Comment: actually it works like this too: 
file=await discord.File(message.attachments[0].url)

wow, so all I needed was an AWAIT.